# minimum and maximum length to delimit my line

Tags: python, matplotlib

Sorry o-for the stupid question but I have been on it for over nearly an hour already. Here is a sample of my dataframe:

```
SEASON       Total
0   2004-2005   4
1   2005-2006   4
2   2006-2007   1
3   2007-2008   7
4   2008-2009   7
5   2009-2010   4
6   2010-2011   4
7   2012-2013   4
8   2013-2014   1
9   2014-2015   2
10  2015-2016   3
11  2016-2017   13
12  2017-2018   18
13  2018-2019   8
```

I have done this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(13,6))
plt.plot(per_year.index, per_year['Total'])
plt.xticks(per_year.index, per_year['SEASON'].unique());
plt.title('AVg assist PER YEAR')
plt.axvline(x=10,color='red', linestyle='--')
plt.axhline(y=3.8,color='orange', xmax=10)
plt.axhline(y=11.75, xmax=10)
plt.tight_layout()
```

All I want is to be able give a max length to my first horizontal line(where it has to stop) and minimum to my second horizontal line to say where it has to finish. I am pretty sure I can do it if change the axis to proper numbers. But I want to keep it as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs: the [xmin and xmax arguments need to be between 0-1](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline.html)

Calculate the scale based on the number of x items

```
xmax = 10/len(per_year.index)
```

Or use the `hline` method of the axes:

```
ax  = plt.gca()
ax.hlines(y=3.8,xmin=0, xmax=10, color='r')
ax.hlines(y=11.75,xmin=0, xmax=10, color='g')
```